# :hover doesn't work when used class to target Font-Awesome icons

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#title {
  background-color: #ff4c68;
  color: white;
}

#title h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.title-img {
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15% 7%;
}


/*Navigation*/

.navbar {
  padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-weight: normal;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 18px 0 18px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.download-btn {
  margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}

.title-img {
  width: 60%;
}


/*Features Section*/

#features h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#features i {
  color: #ef8172;
}

#features i:hover {
  color: #ff4c68;
}

#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.feature-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}

.feature-box h3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.feature-box p {
  color: #8f8f8f;
}


/*Testimonials Section*/

#testimonials {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ef8172;
}

#testimonials h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

@media (max-width:576px) {
  #testimonials h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
  .press-logo {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

.testimonial-img {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

.carousel-item {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 7% 15%;
}


/*Press Section*/

#press {
  background-color: #ef8172;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.press-logo {
  margin: 20px 20px 50px;
}

#pricing {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

#cta {
  background-color: #ff4c68;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#cta h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  #cta h3 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width:576px) {
  #cta h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
}

#footer {
  color: #000;
}

footer span {
  margin: 50px 15px 30px 15px;
}

#footer {
  padding: 0 0 20px;
}

@media (max-width:1028px) {
  .title-img {
    position: static;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  #title {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap /Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/115370f697.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>tindog</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">



      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>




      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="title-img" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Easy to use.</h1>
          <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>





  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">
    <div id="testimonials-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#testimonials-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#testimonials-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonials-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonials-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Press -->





  <section id="press">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">
  </section>





  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h2 class="display-4">A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
      <p class="lead">Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Chihuahua</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title">Free</h2>
                <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
                <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
                <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Labrador</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$49 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h2>
                <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Mastiff</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$99 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h2>
                <p>Pirority Listing</p>
                <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer" class="text-center">
    <span class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></span>
    <span class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg"></span>
    <span class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></span>
    <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>
  </footer>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

My problem is when I use an `"i"` tag to select the font-awesome icons to change hover property, it works really well. But if I use a class to do the same thing it doesn't work.I did it correctly by targeting them with `#features i:hover{ color: black;}` ,but when I use `.fa:hover{ color: black;}` ,It doesn't work?

Comment: Code you simplify your code sample and elaborate on what you are looking for.

Comment: Do we really need to read your 500 lines of code to understand this problem?  keep it simple and read carefully: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

i think the issue is you targeting `.fa` while your your `i` tags has the class `fas` and `fab`.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, you use some `fa` classes but you use `fas` and `fab` classes too,

```
<span class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></span>
<i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-4x"></i>
<span class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></span>
```

You must include each of them in your CSS like this

```
.fa:hover,
.fas:hover,
.fab:hover { color: black; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have change the **font awesome** color in **features section** only.

There is no **`fa` class** in features section. But exists **fas** and **fa-somewords** [somewords means check-circle,.... ]

```
<i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-4x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
<i class="fas fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
```

Then, try this

```
#features .fas{
  color: #ef8172;
}
#features .fas:hover{
   color:black;
}
```

instead of

```
#features i {
  color: #ef8172;
}

#features i:hover {
  color: #ff4c68;
}
```

**Live Demo**

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#title {
  background-color: #ff4c68;
  color: white;
}

#title h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.title-img {
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15% 7%;
}


/*Navigation*/

.navbar {
  padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-weight: normal;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 18px 0 18px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.download-btn {
  margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}

.title-img {
  width: 60%;
}


/*Features Section*/

#features h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.feature-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}

.feature-box h3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.feature-box p {
  color: #8f8f8f;
}


/*Testimonials Section*/

#testimonials {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ef8172;
}

#testimonials h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

@media (max-width:576px) {
  #testimonials h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
  .press-logo {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

.testimonial-img {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

.carousel-item {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 7% 15%;
}


/*Press Section*/

#press {
  background-color: #ef8172;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.press-logo {
  margin: 20px 20px 50px;
}

#pricing {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

#cta {
  background-color: #ff4c68;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#cta h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  #cta h3 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width:576px) {
  #cta h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
}

#footer {
  color: #000;
}

footer span {
  margin: 50px 15px 30px 15px;
}

#footer {
  padding: 0 0 20px;
}

@media (max-width:1028px) {
  .title-img {
    position: static;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  #title {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
#features .fas{
  color: #ef8172;
}
#features .fas:hover{
   color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap /Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/115370f697.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>tindog</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">



      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>




      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="title-img" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Easy to use.</h1>
          <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>





  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">
    <div id="testimonials-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#testimonials-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#testimonials-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonials-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonials-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Press -->





  <section id="press">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">
  </section>





  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h2 class="display-4">A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
      <p class="lead">Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Chihuahua</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title">Free</h2>
                <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
                <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
                <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Labrador</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$49 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h2>
                <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Mastiff</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$99 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h2>
                <p>Pirority Listing</p>
                <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer" class="text-center">
    <span class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></span>
    <span class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg"></span>
    <span class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></span>
    <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>
  </footer>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

You can also try this

```
#features [class*="fa-"] {
  color: #ef8172;
}
#features [class*="fa-"]:hover{
   color:black;
}
```

To get all `fa-* class` by `[class*="fa-"]`

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

#title {
  background-color: #ff4c68;
  color: white;
}

#title h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.title-img {
  width: 60%;
  transform: rotate(25deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 30%;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15% 7%;
}


/*Navigation*/

.navbar {
  padding: 0 0 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu';
  font-weight: normal;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 18px 0 18px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 200;
}

.download-btn {
  margin: 5% 3% 5% 0;
}

.title-img {
  width: 60%;
}


/*Features Section*/

#features h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.feature-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}

.feature-box h3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
}

.feature-box p {
  color: #8f8f8f;
}


/*Testimonials Section*/

#testimonials {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: #ef8172;
}

#testimonials h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

@media (max-width:576px) {
  #testimonials h2 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
  .press-logo {
    width: 25%;
  }
}

.testimonial-img {
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 20px;
}

.carousel-item {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding: 7% 15%;
}


/*Press Section*/

#press {
  background-color: #ef8172;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3%;
}

.press-logo {
  margin: 20px 20px 50px;
}

#pricing {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

#cta {
  background-color: #ff4c68;
}

#footer {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#cta h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #fff;
}

@media (max-width:992px) {
  #cta h3 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width:576px) {
  #cta h3 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 1.2;
  }
}

#footer {
  color: #000;
}

footer span {
  margin: 50px 15px 30px 15px;
}

#footer {
  padding: 0 0 20px;
}

@media (max-width:1028px) {
  .title-img {
    position: static;
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  #title {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
#features [class*="fa-"] {
  color: #ef8172;
}
#features [class*="fa-"]:hover{
   color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap /Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700;900&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/115370f697.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>tindog</title>
</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">



      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#pricing">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">Download</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>




      <!-- Title -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h1>Meet new and interesting dogs nearby.</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <img class="title-img" src="images/iphone6.png" alt="iphone-mockup">
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>


  </section>


  <!-- Features -->

  <section id="features">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-check-circle fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Easy to use.</h1>
          <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-bullseye fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Elite Clientele</h3>
        <p>We have all the dogs, the greatest dogs.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="feature-box col-lg-4">
        <i class="fas fa-heart fa-4x"></i>
        <h3>Guaranteed to work.</h3>
        <p>So easy to use, even your dog could do it.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>





  <!-- Testimonials -->

  <section id="testimonials">
    <div id="testimonials-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#testimonials-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#testimonials-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
          <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
          <img class="testimonial-img" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
          <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonials-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonials-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </section>


  <!-- Press -->





  <section id="press">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/techcrunch.png" alt="tc-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/tnw.png" alt="tnw-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/bizinsider.png" alt="biz-insider-logo">
    <img class="press-logo" src="images/mashable.png" alt="mashable-logo">
  </section>





  <!-- Pricing -->

  <section id="pricing">

    <div class="pricing-header px-3 py-3 pt-md-5 pb-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      <h2 class="display-4">A Plan for Every Dog's Needs</h2>
      <p class="lead">Simple and affordable price plans for your and your dog.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="card-deck mb-3 text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Chihuahua</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title">Free</h2>
                <p>5 Matches Per Day</p>
                <p>10 Messages Per Day</p>
                <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-outline-dark">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Labrador</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$49 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h2>
                <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">Mastiff</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title pricing-card-title">$99 <small class="text-muted">/ mo</small></h2>
                <p>Pirority Listing</p>
                <p>Unlimited Matches</p>
                <p>Unlimited Messages</p>
                <p>Unlimited App Usage</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-dark">Sign Up</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Call to Action -->

  <section id="cta">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <h3>Find the True Love of Your Dog's Life Today.</h3>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-apple"></i> Download</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg download-btn"><i class="fab fa-google-play"></i> Download</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer" class="text-center">
    <span class="fab fa-twitter fa-lg"></span>
    <span class="fab fa-facebook fa-lg"></span>
    <span class="fab fa-instagram fa-lg"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></span>
    <p>© Copyright 2018 TinDog</p>
  </footer>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>

</html>
```